# Excel VBA - Referencing HTML <div> Attributes

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I've been struggling for days now to write some code that will output the value of 'data-full-name' from a webpages source code (Link to screenshot below).

I know I can access the value of 'class' for instnace using objCollection(i).className, but how do I access other div attributes?

Thank you!

#### Webpage Source Code ScreenShot

[image: Webpage Source Code ScreenShot]

```
Private Sub Extract_Info()

Dim i As Long
Dim ie As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = False

ie.navigate "http://mywebpage.com.au/"

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

'Begin extraction
Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")

i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
   
   If objCollection(i).ClassName = "listing listing-search listing-data" Then

       'Not sure how to code here:
       e.g. MsgBox (objCollection(i).data-full-name)
               
   End If
   
i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Debug.Print objCollection(i).getAttribute("data-full-name")
```